# PLC Visual Basic Program: "Conversion from type 'Counter' to type 'Integer' is not valid"

Tags: vb.net, plc

I have a program that reads data points from a PLC over a network connection.

The exception

> "Conversion from type 'Counter' to type 'Integer' is not valid"

occurs when I try to read from a C file on an Allen Bradley PLC-5.

The type listed for the C file is Counter, but there is no counter type in Visual Basic.
Is there any type that a "counter" type will accept in Visual Basic? Changing the return type for the Function to `Counter` or `CounterSample` doesn't help.

Here is the code for the relevant function. I am using an Automated Solutions Ascomm.net driver.

```
Public Function readValueCounter(item As Item, num As Integer) As Integer
    Try
        'read in the data for ASComm object instances
        item.Read()
        'return value
        Return item.Values(num)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'report error
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return 0
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: What is `item` and where are you getting the exception at `Item.Read()?`

Comment: I'm certain that `C` doesn't have a `Counter`. Also there is no reference on the internet at all to that error in vb.net. Is the error generated by the vb program? Have you defined a Class or Structure in your program called `Counter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the driver that you are using, but it sounds like you are trying to have it read the base address of the counter - say C5:0, but the function is looking for an integer tag, not the full counter structure.

I would suspect that you are trying to return either the Preset or the Accum values.

Try adding .ACC or .PRE to your tag to see if that will return the value with out error. (ie: C5:0.ACC)